# Remote Perfmon Is Super Slow

Tags: windows, perfmon

I'm trying to use perfmon to monitor some servers, but adding counters is excruciatingly slow. Each click freezes the window for tens of seconds. How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

Consider learning how to use powershell to automate performance counter work:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849685.aspx

You can use the `Get-Counter -ListSet * -ComputerName MyRemoteComputer` to list out all the counters on a remote computer.  From there you can use `Get-Counter` to collect counter data remotely, and the `Export-Counter` cmdlet to export to log files suitable for review in perfmon.